# How to use GetViewProjMatrix().TransformVector(LineDirection) in UE4?

Tags: projections

I try to project a 3D vector (a direction, not a position) in screen space, but it does not return satisfying results:

```
 FVector LineDirectionOnScreen = 
   EdMode->ViewMatrices.GetViewProjMatrix().TransformVector(LineDirection);
 FVector2D LineDirectionOnScreen2D(
   LineDirectionOnScreen.X * 0.5f * (float)EdMode->ViewRect.Width(), 
   LineDirectionOnScreen.Y * 0.5f * (float)EdMode->ViewRect.Height());
```

When `LineDirection` is (0,0,1) it always returns a something like (0,Y) (Y can be anything), no matter how the camera is rotated.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: [Please explain why you downvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes) when you do.

Comment: I dont know why it was downvoted. but this seems like a close dupllicate to your other question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can simply use `TransformVector` when the matrix you're transforming by involves a projection matrix. To fully project to screen space, you have to divide by W, which `TransformVector` doesn't do (it simply multiplies by the matrix without translation).

Also, because of the divide by W, transforming *vectors* (as opposed to *points*) by a projection matrix is probably not what you actually want. If what you want is the screen-space vector between two points, you should transform and divide-by-W each point, then subtract them to get a screen-space vector. Otherwise the vector will likely be inaccurate.

Comment: Ok, thanks for this answer! I used `TransformVector` after reading the first paragraph of [this page about homogenous coordinates](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-3-matrices/). I understood I should not worry about W when projecting a direction, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: I thought about projecting both points on my screen, but I changed my mind because I thought it was not necessary.

Comment: @arthur.sw That article is OK as far as affine transforms go, but when projections get involved, things are more complicated.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have more details about this, maybe I should ask this question on [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @arthur.sw What details are you interested in? I could add a quick example showing how the divide-by-W affects vectors, if that would be helpful.

Comment: Well I just wanted to make sure that projecting two points is the only or best way to do it.